# Angular directive, refer to element content inside template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a directive that conditionally adds a line break if an angular expression is non-blank.  So far, I have this:

```
// this will show text with a <br> conditionally if the text is non-blank
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('brIf', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            text: '='
        },
        template: '<span ng-show="text && text.trim().length">{{ text }}<br/></span>'
    };
});
```

Which works if I use it like this (any part of the address might be undefined or blank):

```
<br-if text="address.number + ' ' + address.street + ' ' + address.apt"></br-if>
```

But what I really want is a directive I can use like this:

```
<!-- put a br at the end of all this jazz, only if the expression is not blank -->
<br-if>{{address.number}} {{address.street}} {{address.apt}}</br-if>
```

...to avoid all of the string math and the text= attribute.  I know I can write a link function in my directive that gets at the html content via the element parameter (I think?), but I don't know how to use the contents of that element in the template.  In other words, see my question inside the link function ...

```
// this will show text with a <br> conditionally if the text is non-blank
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('brIf', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            text: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            // I want the text of elm here to be used instead of 'text' 
            // in my template below.  Is this possible?
        },
        template: '<span ng-show="text && text.trim().length">{{ text }}<br/></span>'
    };
});
```

Comment: @EdgarMartinez - can you elaborate?  I'm reading the ng docs about it but can't seem to get what I need (also tried $compile in a directive controller function with not much luck).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion):

```
app.directive('brIf', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span ng-show="text && text.trim().length">{{ text }}<br/></span>',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclusionFn) {

      transclusionFn(scope, function(clone) {

        scope.text = $interpolate(clone[0].innerHTML)(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

What you are after is `clone` which will be a fresh compiled copy of your transcluded content. This means that for example `clone[0].innerHTML` will be:

```
{{address.number}} {{address.street}} {{address.apt}}
```

You can then use the `$interpolate` service to compile the string into an interpolation function, use this function to compute the interpolated string against a scope and use the result:

```
var interpolationFn = $interpolate(clone[0].innerHTML);
var interpolatedString = interpolationFn(scope);
scope.text = interpolatedString;
```

Or simply:

```
scope.text = $interpolate(clone[0].innerHTML)(scope);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/VNauZ0Kkr1HLCnsWTgyO?p=preview

Comment: Great explanation!  Holy cow, I just spent 24hrs trying to make this work on my own, trying parse and eval and transclude.  I was going to try fluxCapacitor next!  Thanks very much.

Comment: Hmm. I see it working in plunker, but in my project, no dice.  I can see scope.text getting set properly in the debugger, but when I inspect the final rendering, it looks empty, like: <span ng-show="text && text.trim().length" class="ng-binding ng-hide"><br></span>.  This happens no matter what I put inside the tag.  Any idea what might be different about my project?

Comment: Is there any asynchronous loading involved? Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/uo963Ilwv81aoVdICrUz?p=preview

Comment: Yes that was it.  Thanks so much.  But I guess that scope param is the parent scope?? It seems to be shared between instances of the directive, making multiple br-if tags turn out equal to the last one interpreted.  I'm going to futz with your implementation, to see if I can set variables on a scope thats private to each instance.

Comment: Adding `scope: true` will fix that: http://plnkr.co/edit/RqOXFROq00kjKaAJhlZf?p=preview

Comment: @tasserKATT - again, really appreciate your help.  I wouldn't have been able to figure this out with it.  I forked the plnker to make a working copy.  Couldn't really figure out the scope thing, but I realized that we could skip the template altogether and just replace the element.  Have a look here (http://plnkr.co/edit/Ihy4oVFEEq8wQ41z0ESp?p=preview).  I'm a noob, so its quite possible a bungled this in some other way, but it appears to work in the limited test.

Comment: I dumbly forked the wrong version of your plunker.  The replace idea works on your new copy, too.  I think I'll go with that.  Thanks again, especially for the followup here.

Comment: @tasserKATT, fyi - discovered this didn't work for child scopes (like ng-repeat="address in addressList") and I gave up.

Comment: Removed the following from the $watch: `if (newValue === oldValue) return;`

Comment: $interpolate saved my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a full `transclusionFn` for most cases. If you set `transclude: true` in your directive options, you can just add `ng-transclude` to your template where you want the content added:

```
<div class="example" style="background: blue; height: 30px; width: 30px" ng-transclude></div>
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697788/175830